# Alternatives for NOT using MERGE INTO in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I was using the following with success:

```
    MERGE INTO table_name tab1 
    USING (SELECT ID,(NVL(col1,0) - NVL(LAG(NVL(col1,0),1) OVER 
(PARTITION BY type order by ID),0)) VAL FROM table_name) bb 
    ON (tab1.ID = bb.ID)
    WHEN matched THEN
      UPDATE SET tab1.col2 = bb.VAL;
```

which is basically an UPDATE on the same table by using operations on the same table.The sub-query returns MORE than one row, this is important.

Here is my table and the results:

[image: my data]

Now i want to do the same but avoiding MERGE INTO, and I've tried the following with no success:

```
    UPDATE 
    (SELECT aa.COL2 as OLD, (NVL(aa.COL1,0) - NVL(LAG(NVL(aa.COL1,0),1) 
OVER (PARTITION BY aa.TYPE order by aa.ID),0)) AS NEW
     FROM table_name aa
     INNER JOIN table_name bb
     ON aa.ID = bb.ID
    ) t
    SET t.OLD = t.NEW;
```

The latest SQL code is giving me this:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
01732. 00000 -  "data manipulation operation not legal on this view"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you shared with us the reason you don't want to use MERGE, which seems like the best solution for this type of problem.

Comment: Because the MERGE INTO has started giving me the following error: 'no more data from socket', and I've been told by my bosses better not to change the DB settings.

Comment: And you determined that the reason for that error is MERGE INTO? How did you conclude that?

Comment: I didn't conclude anything, I was told to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
update table_name t
    set col2 = col1 - coalesce( (select max(col1) keep (dense_rank first order by t2.id desc)
                                 from table_name t2
                                 where t2.type = t.type and t2.id < t.id
                                ), 0);
```

This is a different approach but it doesn't use `merge`.

Comment: I´ll try this tomorrow and give you feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: Well, this populates col2 with exactly the same values as in col1, it is not what I am looking for, it doesn't give you the values I was posting (see my image above) which is basically the subtraction of col1 values by using just the previous row's value.

Comment: @Web-GISentrepreneur . . . The `order by` should be `desc`.